# rsync and include / exclude. How hard can it be?

Tags: rsync, copy

I'm trying to recursively copy a directory / file structure from one directory to another, keeping only html files. Should be a simple case of include / exclude shouldn't it?

I just want to print out the files first. When I get that right, I'll copy them.

```
rsync -a --list-only -v SOURCEDIR --exclude='.*' --include='**/*.html'
```

Gives me all the files.

```
rsync -a --list-only -v SOURCEDIR --include='**/*.html' --exclude='*'
```

and

```
rsync -a --list-only -v SOURCEDIR --include='*.html' --exclude='*' 
rsync -a --list-only -v SOURCEDIR --include=*.html --exclude=*
```

Give me no files.

```
rsync -a --list-only -v SOURCEDIR --include='*.html' --exclude='*.*'
```

Looks like it gives me the whole directory structure and only html files. But I don't want empty directories.

Help!

On Mac OS 10.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered using find to do your hard work?

Something along the lines of

```
find ./ -name "*.html" -exec rsync -R {} /target/base/directory/ \;
```

will recreate the directory tree of ./ in which html files are found, and build the same under /target/base/directory

Answer (score 12):

Rsync can be confusing about selective copies like this.  I use the following to do the task that you're asking for:

```
rsync -avP \
--filter='+ */' \
--filter='+ **/*.html' \
--filter='- *' \
--prune-empty-dirs \
--delete \
/source/ \
/dest/
```

Basically you need to include all directories in the search, then add all `*.html` files to the list, the exclude all other files.

The `--prune-empty-dirs` option is handy to use as it excludes any directory that doesn't have a `*.html` file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this is the best[0] way to do it, but you can add a very slight tweak to your last attempt and make it work.  Just add the *prune directories* option (`--prune or -m`).

```
rsync -am --list-only -v SOURCEDIR --include='*.html' --exclude='*.*'
```

[0] By 'best', I mean the cleanest and most efficient way.  It seems like there should be a more elegant way of expressing this, but I don't know offhand what it is.

Comment: You forgot to add it.

Comment: No I didn't.  It's at the beginning there, 'rsync -am'.  I coupled the '-m' with the '-a'.